# how do I set the record right?

Tags: performance-reviews

I was in a team for 6 months and i did a good job. I switched teams recently due to various reasons. The performance review was done by old manager and his comments aren't true. I believe it is a reaction to leaving the team. I want to set the record straight with my new manager. Do i wait to see if my new manager asks questions about the review?

Comment: Are you suffering any tangible penalties because of this review?  (ie" new manager punishing you somehow, missed opportunity for a raise, etc)  If not, I'd say don't worry about it.  Complaining just makes you look petty, but time will prove your worth to the new manager, unless you have a more urgent need/goal that requires action.  Do you have such?

Comment: @Steve-O Penalties aren't always immediate.  If the company's management changes and they decide to downsize, people who got bad reviews are going to be easy targets.  You don't want something like this in your file.

Comment: *Who* says you did a good job? (other than you, obviously)

Comment: @Philip: My past manager and team lead told i am doing a good job in 1:1. that's why i found this review surprising.

Comment: What sort of proof do you have to the contrary? What in the reviews do you have evidence against?

Answer (score 4):

> how do I set the record right?

Most companies have as part of the performance review process a place where you can comment on your review. Use that.

Make comments that indicate why you believe your performance exceeded your ratings. And point out anything specific that you feel is inaccurate. But skip the "I believe it is a reaction to leaving the team." unless you talk it over with your past manager beforehand and that manager agrees. Try not to come across as whining or overly defensive. Don't criticize your former team or manager. Acknowledge any actual deficiencies in your performance - nobody is perfect.

Be aware though that your new manager will likely judge you based on your performance on your new team and will probably not care much if at all how your past manager judged you. At least that what I always did.

Your comments are unlikely to change anyone's attitude toward you, but at least you will have them on record.